# Returning a class type in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

i am sorry to ask again,

but i been trying to go over this error for a while:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class time{
   private:
      int m;
      int h;
   public:
      time():m(0),h(0) {};
      time(int x,int y): m(x),h(y) {}
      int getm() const {return this->m;}
      int geth() const {return this->h;}
      void print() const;
      time operator+(time aa);
      time operator-(const time &a) const;
 };

 void time::print() const
 {
    cout <<"Hour: "<<h<<endl<<"Mins: "<<m<<endl;
 }

 time  time::operator+( time &a)
 {
   time temp;
   temp.m= this->m+a.getm();
   temp.h=this->h+a.geth();
   return temp;
 }


 int main ()
 {  
   return 0;
 }
```

i am getting an error stating that time does not name a type, i am not so sure of the error, it should work.

also regarding pointers

given i have a double pointer pointing to a pointer and that pointer pointing to a dynamic data.

```
int *ptr=new int
int **p=&ptr;

delete p;
```

so will delete p, first delete dynamic data, then the pointer ptr ?

Comment: No delete p will not delete the dynamic data.

Comment: what if the pointer ptr was created dynamically, would it now only delete the ptr?

Comment: Your need `delete *p`. If you had `int **p = new *int` then `delete p` would work -

Comment: Don't put two separate questions in one post.  If you have a second question, make another post.

Comment: i would, but i feel guilty making a whole thread for just a small question, sorry will do next time

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that "time" is a function in the C standard library, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/).  Try naming the class something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct method declaration or definition.

```
                            |----- Remove reference operator
                            V
time  time::operator+( time &a)
 {
   time temp;
   temp.m= this->m+a.getm();
   temp.h=this->h+a.geth();
   return temp;
 }
```

Comment: i am not so sure why you are telling me to remove it, i am trying to avoid making a copy of a

Comment: So change the declaration - `time operator+(time &aa);`

Comment: I would keep the reference, but make it a const reference `time operator+(const time& a)`.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question

> Given I have a double pointer pointing to a pointer and that pointer pointing to a dynamic data.

```
int *ptr=new int;
int **p=&ptr;

delete p;
```

> So will `delete p`, first delete dynamic data, then the pointer `ptr`?

No! And you shouldn't delete `p` at all, as it is not created using `new`.

The rule is very simple, `new` and `delete` come in pairs. If you create something using `new`, you should destroy it using `delete` (and exactly once).

In your case the proper way is to `delete ptr` as that was created using new. As a slightly confusing option you can instead use `delete *p`, as `p` points to `ptr`.